# WP7 How to change the ellipses color in the application bar?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, expression-blend, application-bar

I have an app bar with custom colors to match the page color of our application. I have managed to get the images and app bar itself to the colors I want, but not the ellipses at the top right. I have set the background color to white and the foreground color to blue. In expression blend, it looks like the ellipses are set to blue, but when I run the app, they are white (same color as the app bar background) and basically invisible. Is there a way to change the color of the ellipses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why it does not work for you but following code in sample application worked for me:

```
<shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True"
                      IsMenuEnabled="True" 
                      ForegroundColor="Orange">
```

I created a new PivotApplication project for Windows Phone. In a new page, I added `ForegroundColor` property to application bar and it worked.

[image]

Comment: Did it work when you ran it in the emulator as well? For me, it shows up in blend with the foreground color, but not on the emulator. Using your exact xaml, it doesn't work for me.